# Yielding control in Java asynchronous code

Tags: java, kotlin, future, completable-future

I come from a Rust/C#/Javascript background for asynchronous programming, and trying to understand comparable Java idioms. Specifically, I'm trying to understand whether there's a "green threads" model, in which a task runs on a thread, and once it reaches a point where it waits on I/O, it suspends itself (in other languages it would be represented by the `await` or `suspend` keywords) and allows another task to run.

From what I see, `CompletableFuture` can run asynchronously, but it doesn't release the thread that runs it - if you execute 1000 futures concurrently, you'll need 1000 threads, or depending on your executor, you might use less threads, but you'll also execute less tasks concurrently.

Are there other mechanisms that allow me to perform a large amount of concurrent I/O operations with a limited number of threads? Maybe Kotlin's Coroutines, or Virtual Threads (I prefer not to rely on Virtual Threads, since they require a relatively new version of Java)?

To clarify - I'm looking for an answer that can be exposed to any JVM application, regardless of language. So I don't care about language implementation, only that the API doesn't bind the caller to the language by some assumption.

Comment: This is what virtual threads are intended to overcome. I think your question is a bit too broad to answer.  Essentially, you can use a [cached threadpool executor](https://docs.oracle.com/en%2Fjava%2Fjavase%2F11%2Fdocs%2Fapi%2F%2F/java.base/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newCachedThreadPool()) and it will accomplish what you're after. After that you need to show that you have a performance problem.

Comment: Also, are you looking for how to do this in Java or how to do this in Kotlin? The answers would vary wildly.

Comment: I agree, there are literally whole books about asynchronous models and it is not that easy to grasp the topic in a few sentences. Generally speaking, all asynchronous models work pretty similarly under the hood and there is almost nothing we can do with one and can't do with another. But their "API" differ greatly. We have callbacks, futures/promises, reactive streams, coroutines/green threads. For example, by using `CompletableFuture` we could wait for an async task by providing listeners and this way we don't block the thread while waiting. We can run 1000 concurrent tasks using 8 threads.

Comment: @Leviathan I added a clarification about the language. I hope that works.

Answer (score 1):

Virtual threads is what you're looking for within the JDK itself.

Otherwise project-reactor, popularly through spring-webflux achieves the same, but by introducing a declarative code style.

Answer (score -2):

If your I/O operation are small as a task you can use fork/join https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/forkjoin.html

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).